# Trying to figure out how a table in SQL Server is getting populated

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is no documentation and no way to get in touch with the architects of the table. Are there any queries or options in SSMS that allows me to know what the table is connected to ?

A brief explanation of my issue is that there are two tables that seem to be connected.

Table A which contain 10M distinct users and Table B 5M users. All users in Table B are in Table A but obviously Table A's users aren't in Table B. After running multiple tests on the website, I cant find the trigger that copies the user information from Table A to Table B. And that's why I would like to know how Table B gets populated.

Comment: There *is* a lot of documentation on how data is stored. The placement of data pages, extents and fields on files is never needed for querying though. Why are you asking this?

Comment: `what the table is connected to` what does that mean? What `architects of the table`? You mean who *created* the table?

Comment: SQL Server Profiler (`Tools > SQL Server Profiler` in SSMS) will allow you to view what queries are being run against the database

Comment: BTW there's a lot of documentation about storage, filegroups, tables and how to find them using system tables and DMVs too.

Comment: ive just elaborated my question to make it more clear guys @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @Ismafoot there are no "connected" tables. Data appears in a table because an INSERT query run. It could be a trigger, a scheduled job, an application. Use Extended Events or SQL Server Profiler to capture the statements that modify the tables

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That makes it more clear thank you . However, I might not have access to this option...

Comment: @Ismafoot ask the DBA what's going on then. That sounds more like a *project management* problem

Comment: you could try SQL Audit https://mohammaddarab.com/create-database-audit-for-insert-update-delete-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Diado already said, try running a profiler for a while.  It will log queries against the database (e.g. `INSERT ...` and `UPDATE ...`), the source of the connection (e.g. IP address), and sometimes the process name.  That could provide clues into what's interacting with your table in question.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-2017